# jquery json not returning value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to submit a form using serialize and all is well except if I input more than 1 box. If I input 1 box, the msg.box appears in #BA_addbox. If however I enter more than 1 box using , as delimiter, then no msg is shown and no json tab appears in firebug. just the html which is correct. Where have I gone wrong with code.

I have created an array and using foreach with explode to seperate the values but no multiple value being returned. Thanks

**UPDATE:** vars are being collected in the php script like thus:

php code

```
$dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customerdept']);
$company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_customer']);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customeraddress']);
$service = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_service']);
$box = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_box']);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['BA_destdate']);
$destdate = $date - > format('Y-m-d');
$authorised = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_authorised']);
$submit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submit']);

$array = explode(",", $_POST['BA_box']);

     if (isset($_POST['submit']))   {
        foreach ($array as $box) {

        //$sql = "INSERT INTO `act` (service, activity, company, address, department, user, destroydate, date, item, new) VALUES ('$service', '$activity', '$company', '$address', '$dept', '$authorised', '$destdate', NOW(), '$box', 1)";
        //$result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        $form=array('dept'=>$dept,
                 'company'=>$company,
                 'address'=>$address,
                 'service'=>$service,
                 'box'=>$box,
                 'destroydate'=>$destdate,
                 'authorised'=>$authorised,
                 'submit'=>$submit);
        $result=json_encode($form);

        echo $result;


   } 
  }
```

jquery code

```
submitHandler: function()   {
                if ($("#BA_boxform").valid() === true)  { 
                var data = $("#BA_boxform").serialize();
                $.post('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php', data, function(msg) {
                $("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered box(es): " + "<b>" + msg.box + "</b><br /> You may now close this window.");
                $("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
                }, 'json');

         } else

         { 
           return; 
         }
        },
        success:    function(msg)   {
                //$("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered a box");
                //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
        }
```

Comment: If your PHP loop processes more than one item you're producing invalid JSON as your response, because it echoes out several pieces of JSON one after the other (which doesn't form up to become one large JSON string). You need to use the loop to create an array with all of the data and then use `json_encode()` _after_ the loop.

Comment: First of all `mysql` API is deprecated. Secondly, escaping string with `mysql_real_escape_string` does not protect you from XSS attacks.

Comment: @PLB thanks for that but how does that help with my problem?

Comment: @nnnnnn i have tried your sggestion but all I get in console is 'msg is null'. Could you do fiddle to illustrate how to do correct json markup based on my code. thanks

Comment: @user1532468 I was not aiming to solve this problem. I just gave you notification. ;) IMO, it's important not to pass by when you see something wrong.

Comment: @PLB thx for that :-) about as useful as a chocolate teapot

Comment: try to place code `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before  `echo $result;`

Comment: @softsdev still getting msg in null. thanks

Comment: check where exact your script miss using consol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @nnnnnn:

Your resulting json looks like the structure below if there is more than one box. This is invalid json, and therefore can not be reliably parsed.

```
{
  ...
}{
  ...
}
```

To fix this, you have to add the arrays to another array, then encode the parent array.

```
$box = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_box']);
$array = explode(",", $_POST['BA_box']);
$output = Array();

if (isset($_POST['submit']))   {
  foreach ($array as $box) {

    //$sql = "INSERT INTO `act` (service, activity, company, address, department, user, destroydate, date, item, new) VALUES ('$service', '$activity', '$company', '$address', '$dept', '$authorised', '$destdate', NOW(), '$box', 1)";
    //$result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $form=array('dept'=>$dept,
                'company'=>$company,
                'address'=>$address,
                'service'=>$service,
                'box'=>$box,
                'destroydate'=>$destdate,
                'authorised'=>$authorised,
                'submit'=>$submit);

    //Add to a parent array instead
    $output[] = $form;

  }

  //encode the entire array
  $result = json_encode( $output );

  echo $result;
}
```

This will result in the following structure and for a variable `data` that contains the parsed json each box can be retrieved via `data[0]`, `data[1]` etc.

```
[
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please explain the data[0] code for me. How would I retrieve values based on my original code. thanks

Comment: I have no clue what you want to display. In your javascript: `data[0]` will return the structure for the first box (e.g. what you put in $form in your php script). `data.length` returns the amount of boxes that are send back.

Answer (score 1):

First fix the php to return a valid json array.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))   {
  foreach ($array as $box) {

    //$sql = "INSERT INTO `act` (service, activity, company, address, department, user, destroydate, date, item, new) VALUES ('$service', '$activity', '$company', '$address', '$dept', '$authorised', '$destdate', NOW(), '$box', 1)";
    //$result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $form=array('dept'=>$dept,
             'company'=>$company,
             'address'=>$address,
             'service'=>$service,
             'box'=>$box,
             'destroydate'=>$destdate,
             'authorised'=>$authorised,
             'submit'=>$submit);
    $result[]=$form;

  }
  echo json_encode( $result );
}
```

Then the *msg* parameter in the post callback should be an array of results, so you can't just do `msg.box` to get the list of boxes. I would suggest something like this:

```
boxes = jQuery.map(msg,function(item){
  return item.box;
}).join(',');
```

That extracts the box property from each item in the array and joins them into a comma separated list. You can then display that list like this:

```
$("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered box(es): " + "<b>" + boxes + 
  "</b><br /> You may now close this window.");
```

Given these changes, your code works for me. If you're having other problems, I suggest you post more of your html - in particular your form structure. It's possible your form isn't submitted the correct values to get a valid response from the server.

Comment: I am getting error: length = elems.length, in jquery.js. I have made a fiddle to show the code I am using. Can you check for error please. thanks http://jsfiddle.net/T2NuC/1/

Comment: Your php is missing a semicolon at the end of this line: `$result[]=$form`. Also you're going to have to assign some values to the variables $dept, $company, $address, etc. I would suggest you hardcode some strings initially.

Comment: james Strange but when I posted code there was a semi coln. def one in my code. The values are being assigned using serialize are they not? However, still getting error. Please see my update in OP. thanks

Comment: You haven't initialised the $submit variable. Also you should be aware that `mysql_real_escape_string` won't work if you haven't opened a database connection with `mysql_connect`. I'm also not sure why you're calling that on the values you're going to be returning in the json object - that only makes sense if you're using those values in a database query.

Comment: James I am making a db query just not shown in code. In my code I have: $submit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submit']); and I have update OP with code. Can you please explain how I haven't initialized the $submit variable with an example as I am fairly new to jquery. I have updated fiddle with code. http://jsfiddle.net/T2NuC/3/ thanks

Comment: The problem is without seeing your full code I have to guess which parts you've deliberately left out and which parts are a mistake. For example, I'm assuming your javascript is part of a bigger class structure, because if that's all there is to it, it's certainly not going to work. I'm assuming your html has a form with all the appropriate fields, and an element with the appropriate id for the results. All of these things are potential problems but I can't tell without seeing all of your code.

Comment: One obvious error I can still see in the current php you've shown me is the call to `$date - > format`. There should be no space between the `-` and the `>`. That should be `$date -> format`.